# A question about the usage of ては and ても

Tags: て-form, particle-は, particle-も

Why can't use も or は in the following sentence:

> 易しい質問に答えられなくて（は・も）、とても恥ずかしかった。

In the case of ても, I was told it probably has to do with 逆条件.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. 易しい質問に答えられなく**ては**、とても恥ずかしかった。 The usage of negative-ては presents a specific case, which must be followed by a judgement/statement of inability. 恥ずかしかった is a personal feeling that has arisen as a result of not knowing the answer, not an objective judgement.

   - (Possible negative-ては option: 易しい質問に答えられなくて**は**、**だめだ**。"Not being able to answer easy questions (as opposed to being able to answer them) is **bad**." Replacing だめだ with いけない or ならない holds the same meaning.
   - Another option: 易しい質問に答えられなくて**は**、**大丈夫だよ**。"Not being able to answer easy questions (as opposed to, e.g., not being able to write by hand) is **okay**.")
2. 易しい質問に答えられなく**ても**、とても恥ずかしかった。 When using a negative-ても, the clause following must present information that goes against the assumption upon hearing the first clause (as you wrote, we must have a 逆{ぎゃく}条件{じょうけん}, literally "opposite condition"). Since one would naturally assume that the subject would be 恥ずかしい because they cannot answer simple questions, the second clause does not satisfy as a 逆条件.

   - (Possible negative-ても option: 易しい質問に答えられなくて**も**、恥ずかしく**なかった**。 "**Even when** (the subject) could not answer a simple question, (subject) was **not** embarrassed.")

「易しい質問に答えられなくて、とても恥ずかしかった。」 Using neither は nor も is the most natural sounding for your meaning here. て connects the two clauses by saying "(the subject) could not answer simple question, and/so (subject) was embarrassed."

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I do not question what you said on ては because it matches what I recall I read on it but would you have any references addressing it (so that I can use it as a refresher)

Comment: Hmm. I don't have a reference for the wording that I used. Most sources I'm seeing just talk about negative-ては in reference to _obligation_, which I guess is similar to what I said, because what creates the obligation to do something is the judgement of whether that thing is good or bad. [This Georgia Tech grammar guide](http://mkikuchi.faculty.gatech.edu/WebCTVista/JAPN2002/contents/Lesson26/26.1/26.1.1g.html) is a good refresher on that form. I'll follow up if I find anything else useful!

Comment: Anyway, 答えられなくては 恥ずかしかった is an imaginary or a habitual conditional which means "I would be embarrassed if/when I couldn't answer".

Comment: `易しい質問に答えられなくては、大丈夫だよ。` という文は、おかしいです。「～～に答えられなくて**は** 、大丈夫だよ」なんて言いません。「～～に答えられなくて**も**大丈夫だよ」なら言います。